# can not click on ad banner

Tags: flash, banner

Hi all i have a banner generate by my php code as below :

```
<script language='JavaScript' type='text/javascript'>
     randomstr = new String (Math.random());
     randomstr = randomstr.substring(1,8);
     document.write ("<" + "script language='JavaScript' type='text/javascript' src='" + "http://test.5imedia.vn/adj.php?ts=" + randomstr + "&amp;sid=57953373149" + "'><" + "/script>");
</script>
<noscript>
    <a href='http://test.5imedia.vn/adc.php?sid=57953373149' >
        <img src='http://test.5imedia.vn/adv.php?sid=57953373149' border='0'>
    </a>
</noscript>
```

Please look into this and help me why i can not click to this flash to follow the adv link.

Answer (score 0):

I have pasted your code into an empty html document and launched it in Firefox4, IE8 and Google Chrome and they all show the advert (Tankzors) and open a new window at `http://mclub.vn/Tankzor.htm` when I click on the right hand side of the advert.

It is worth noting that the left hand side of the 'Tankzors' advert where the animation is playing does not open the link when clicked. This is an issue with the flash advert however not that piece of code you have pasted.

**tl;dr version:** *The problem is with the flash document, not the code you pasted.*

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. After dig into this, see that flash need have code on (press)
{
    getURL(clickTAG, "_blank");
}